# joining multidimensional array Into pairs Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

For this program I'm making i need to join together some arrays in a multidimensional array:

What the array is:

```
[["2", "2"]["0", "9"]["2", "2"]["2", "7"]["1", "7"]["0", "8"]["0", "1"]
["0", "9"]]
```

And I want it to become like this:

```
["22", "09", "22", "27", "17", "08", "01", "09"]
```

Sorry if this is a really dumb question but if someone can help me I would be very happy, and if it is impossible to do this, then please tell me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
multi_dimensional_array = [["2", "2"], ["0", "9"], ["2", "2"], ["2", "7"], ["1", "7"], ["0", "8"], ["0", "1"], ["0", "9"]]
multi_dimensional_array.map(&:join)
```

`map` iterates over the entries in your array and returns a copy of the array with modified entries.

`&:join` sends `join` to every member of the iteration by converting the symbol to a block using `Symbol#to_proc`: You can read it as if it expands to:

```
->(entry){ entry.send(:join) }
```

Comment: i have tried using your code, but it didn't work for me, i think i have done something wrong, maybe you know what. First it was 1 large string, then i used .split then i sliced it up using d_array.each_slice(2) { |a| p a } then used your code d_joined_array = d_array_split.map(&:join)

Comment: @RubyDutch I just blindly copied over your array which is missing commas, amended it now :)

Comment: Oh yeah i see, but I still have the problem of it not combining the things inside the array.. I am bad a ruby so maybe i have made mistake

Comment: I've tried it in an other project, and it worked! thanks alot, and i think i have just done something wrong in the other project

Answer (score 1):

Generally the pattern is:

```
list = [["2", "2"],["0", "9"],["2", "2"],["2", "7"],["1", "7"],["0", "8"],["0", "1"],["0", "9"]]

# For each item in the list, transform it...
list.collect do |entry|
  # ...by joining the bits together into a single string.
  entry.join
end
```